# Apply regex to TextField component within a Field component of redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, redux-form

Setting up a form using Google's material-ui components for looks and redux-form to handle the state. I need to apply regex to various inputs to limit what can be entered (i.e. numbers only for an ID, letters and spaces only for name, etc)

Through searching it seems there are ways to do what I need utilizing the `onChange` function of `<TextField>` from material-ui but I found contradictory info when related to the `<Field>` component from redux-form.

I tried adding `onChange` and `pattern` to the `TextField` component without any luck, could still type and paste non-number characters.

Here is my `Field` call:

```
<Field
  disabled={disabled}
  id="classifierId"
  name="classifierId"
  component={renderTextField}
  placeholder="enter an ID"
  className={classes.textFieldWidth}
/>
```

And my `renderTextField`

```
const renderTextField = ({
  input,
  label,
  value,
  meta: { touched, error },
  ...custom
}) => (
    <TextField
      fullWidth
      multiline
      rowsMax="1"
      autoFocus
      margin="normal"
      {...input}
      {...custom}
    />
  )
```

What I need to do is be able to add a regex limiter to the input. So if a user types 'a13059' or if they paste 'a13059' as an ID, the 'a' doesn't even get entered into the input.